# Is there a way to package an ASP.NET Core app area as a NuGet package?

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core app that I would love to publish as a NuGet package that you can add to any Core web project. The app is actually entirely confined to an area (i.e., /Areas/MyArea) in the project, including controllers, views, service classes, models, views, etc., except for a few pieces. Really, these are the pieces that I'd love to magically add to an existing web app:

- The area and everything in it
- Its CSS and JS in wwwroot/lib/myapp
- Entries in the Startup class
- MyApp.json in the root

I know NuGet will restore the package dependencies, but I'm not sure how it would also consider the client-side packages.

Any suggestions? Is NuGet the wrong tool for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Years later, this is possible in ASP.NET Core > v2.x, by using a Razor class library.

Answer (score 1):

currently afaik it is not possible to deliver files into the web app from a nuget package. I think there is some discussion and work going on about making that possible in the future.

The way I'm handling that in my projects is to embed the views and the needed static js and css resources which is done like this in project.json:

"buildOptions": {
        "embed": [ "Views/**", "js/**", "css/**" ]
    },

I created a [controller to serve my static resources](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe/blob/master/src/cloudscribe.Core.Web/Controllers/cscsrController.cs):

```
public class cscsrController : Controller
{  
    private ContentResult GetContentResult(string resourceName, string contentType)
    {
        var assembly = typeof(cscsrController).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        var resourceStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
        string payload;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(resourceStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            payload = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return new ContentResult
        {
            ContentType = contentType,
            Content = payload,
            StatusCode = 200
        };
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ContentResult bootstrapdatetimepickercss()
    {
        return GetContentResult(
            "cloudscribe.Core.Web.css.bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css",
            "text/css");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ContentResult momentwithlocalesjs()
    {
        return GetContentResult(
            "cloudscribe.Core.Web.js.moment-with-locales.min.js",
            "text/javascript");
    }

}
```

then I link to the controller action in the views where I need to load the js and/or css.

To make the embedded views work I created an extension method of RazorViewEngineOptions:

```
public static RazorViewEngineOptions AddEmbeddedViewsForCloudscribeCore(this RazorViewEngineOptions options)
{
    options.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(
            typeof(SiteManager).GetTypeInfo().Assembly,
            "cloudscribe.Core.Web"
        ));

    return options;
}
```

and this must be called from ConfigureServices in the web app [Startup](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe/blob/master/src/example.WebApp/Startup.cs) like this:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorOptions(options =>
    {
        options.AddEmbeddedViewsForCloudscribeCore();

    })
    ;
```

this technique should work the same for areas. Note that one cool thing is that users can download the views and install them locally and that will override the use of the embedded views making it easy to customize some or all views. By overriding the views it is also possible to then manually install the js and css locally if desired and change the views to link to those local files if customization is needed. The end result is my nuget has everything it needs so there is just some startup configuration to get things working.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's true that you can't add files. Some of the DI container libraries do that (StructureMap MVC, for example), I imagine using PowerShell scripts.

Comment: actually you can add files into the package but you can't get them delivered into the app currently for .NET Core nugets afaik https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2262

Comment: I know powershell is now open source and cross platform but not sure if you can really use that in a cross platform way with nuget at least at the moment

Comment: this issue is about you can get views into the nuget but you can't get them out https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1490

Comment: Thanks, Joe, those are really good links. The first one was exactly the cyclical doc mess that I was already in, but the second actually is pretty promising in terms of embedding the views. Perhaps the static content is easy enough from there.